# Calculating Stock movement History

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions

I am currently trying to output Product code and Movement to show a complete history of how many of a product we have sold.

I have two tables `PUB.movement` and `PUB.product`

I've made it this far

```
SELECT   a."prod-code" AS productcode, count(*) AS Movement 
FROM     (SELECT   mov."tran-date", pro."prod-code"   
          FROM     PUB."movement" mov,            
                   PUB."product" pro   
          WHERE    mov.SKU=pro.SKU   
            AND      mov."move-type" = 'i'   
            AND      pro."prod-group" like 'SLA%') a 
GROUP BY a."prod-code"
```

The output generated is:

```
PRODUCTCODE | MOVEMENT
0490786         1
0500012         1
0566003         1
0566004         1
0650594         1
0920127         1
0920154         1
1000557M1       1
1000578M1m      19
```

The only issue I have is if more than one is invoiced at that time it only counts that invoice as 1, not the quantity invoiced. There is a `qty` column in `PUB.movement`. I just can't incorporate it with the current query to output the correct stock movement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want a `SUM()` of the `qty` field rather than a count of movements? Try this:

```
Select pro."prod-code" As productcode, Sum(mov.qty) As Movement
  From PUB.movement As mov
  Inner Join PUB.product As pro On mov.SKU = pro.SKU
  Where mov."move-type" = 'i'
    And pro."prod-group" like 'SLA%'
  Group By pro."prod-code";
```

Comment: Thanks, tried your solution but am getting a Column not found/specified error.

Comment: @Ninsaki typo fixed

Comment: Great! worked a treat. Just had to change SUM(mvt.qty) to SUM (qty)

Comment: What is `mvt` in `Sum(mvt.qty)`? Should it be `Sum(mov.qty)`?